# What is the criteria for "too many incorrect reviews"?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I got the following message when I tried to access the reviews section today.

```
You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should 
have reviewed differently, see: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8661744
```

I'm not sure how common these types of messages are, but I am a little confused because my reviews appear to be in line with what other reviewers are voting, I haven't failed questions that check that I'm paying attention, and I have only missed a single audit question from 120 triage reviews.

Additionally, the linked question that has been provided has been deleted, and my answer is the same as the other reviewers.

What should I change in my reviewing behavior so that I can keep my reviews in line with what the expectations are?

Comment: Well if you suggest "should be improved" on a question that then gets deleted, does it not show that your response was wrong. The question wasn't improved, it was bad enough to be removed...

Comment: To a certain point, but that means that all of the reviewers were wrong.  Is that one review enough to qualify as "too many incorrect reviews"?

Answer (score 25):

Since the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190843/how-to-setup-icon-framework-in-yii2-basic-application-stack-overflow) has been deleted and is only available to 10k+ users, the content of the question was:

> [image: i have implemented teh bootstrap 3 theme in my yii-2 basic application and i want to implement font awesome for it.Any one help me how to implement font awesome widget in bootstrap 3 theme.]

I happened to be reviewing a variety of things and came across this question, which is terribly broad and just awful. I deleted it, and I checked to see how this wound up sticking around for days without being closed, etc. I found that this went through [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8661744), but none of the reviewers felt this was an unsalvageable question which *sort of concerned me*, because I found this to be an obviously bad question.

This ban did not happen because you failed an audit; it happened because I spot-checked several reviews and found quite a few things that were marked as "Looks OK" or "Should Be Improved" when they should have been "unsalvageable" and flagged for closure.  It's only 3 days, and you'll be back to reviewing in no time.

Comment: Should you be letting them know that they have manually been reviewed banned?  I could see this falling through the cracks if the user took few days off from SO and came back after the ban expired.  They would never know that anything happened.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, we don't typically send messages for a ban unless it is behavior that would warrant a message.

Comment: I think I understand where you're coming from, @bluefeet.

Comment: I'm not at all sure that voting "should be improved" vs "unsalvageable" should be considered much of an error.  Both say it's bad as stated.  Looks ok vs unsalvageable is another matter, though.

Comment: @LorenPechtel The terminology is horrible: "should be improved" means that SO users can improve it; "unsalvageable" means that only the OP can improve it.

Comment: Perhaps the definition of "should be improved" is too ambiguous. To quote, "for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable". IMO it's a little unfair to penalize reviewers for marking a question as "should be improved" if the edits from the OP that could make it clear and answerable are not forthcoming. That doesn't seem to be the fault of the reviewers.